# Wordpress Header search box alignment

Tags: css, wordpress

How to change layout of page ? 
Could anyone help me in alignment of the search box in the header?
site: [my site link](http://www.pluzs.net/)
I want the search box to appear at the right to the site logo and below the menu navigation bar.

Comment: Welcome to SO! On SO, linking to your website or another website is not recommended. Please post just the part of the code/CSS that you are having a problem with.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Add clearfix class on logo parent div.
2. Add float: left rule to the element with these 'collapse navbar-collapse' classes
3. Adjust margin of #jqueryslidemenu as per your requirement.